# FragmentTabHost onTaChanged animation not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, fragment-tab-host, fragmentmanager

I have added animations for fragments/tabs in tab host exactly like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109268/1865583

But the animation just wont start...i tried with startAnimation but no effect also...?

This is added in onCreateView method of my Parent Fragment which has mTabHost field...

```
    //On tab changed
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            logInfo("Tab changed id " + tabId);
            currentView = mTabHost.getCurrentView();
            if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() > currentTab)
            {

                previousView.setAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
                currentView.setAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
            }
            else
            {
                previousView.setAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
                currentView.setAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
            }
            previousView = currentView;
            currentTab = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        }
    });


 /**
 * Custom animation that animates in from right
 * 
 * @return Animation the Animation object
 */
private Animation inFromRightAnimation()
{
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    return setProperties(inFromRight);
}

/**
 * Custom animation that animates out to the right
 * 
 * @return Animation the Animation object
 */
private Animation outToRightAnimation()
{
    Animation outToRight = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    return setProperties(outToRight);
}

/**
 * Custom animation that animates in from left
 * 
 * @return Animation the Animation object
 */
private Animation inFromLeftAnimation()
{
    Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    return setProperties(inFromLeft);
}

/**
 * Custom animation that animates out to the left
 * 
 * @return Animation the Animation object
 */
private Animation outToLeftAnimation()
{
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    return setProperties(outtoLeft);
}

/**
 * Helper method that sets some common properties
 * @param animation the animation to give common properties
 * @return the animation with common properties
 */
private Animation setProperties(Animation animation)
{
    animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return animation;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use animations on views like in the normal TabHost since the fragments are detached and attached inside the FragmentTabHost.

Have a look at a [possible solution for animations with FragmentTabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761915/switch-animation-between-fragments-using-fragmenttabhost/29262180#29262180)